# PHP include in a different place

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

I have the following markup:

```
    <?php include 'admin/assets/includes/adminBoot.php'; ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Test Page</title>
        <?php if($loggedIn){ include 'admin/assets/includes/editPageDochead.php'; } ?>
        </head>
    <body>

      <?php if($loggedIn){ include 'admin/assets/includes/adminBar.php'; } ?>
....
```

What I'd like to know is, would it be possible to just have the first php include there, which has some script to place the other 2 php includes in the correct places?

It's part of a CMS I'm building and I want it to be easy enough to integrate by only needing 1 include on each page.
I don't want to have to add these 3 includes to everypage ideally.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you, but I would suggest using template system like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Also I recommend reading something about MVC design pattern.

Comment: in one file  like `head.php` include all needed files..and then only include this file on where ever you want.

Comment: @DS9 the includes exist in their place for a reasons. Includes in the head have CSS links etc. so need to be in that place. The adminBoot include has a session_start so needs to sit above all HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a header.php file with the content you've pasted in your question and then include just that one.

Comment: I'm trying to integrate my CMS into existing sites, so I can't mess with the existing code on those pages, only add includes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the include pages themselves check the logged in status?

```
<?php include 'admin/assets/includes/adminBar.php'; ?>
```

and in the files:

```
<?php
     if($loggedIn)
     {
         // Do yout stuff here.
     }
?>
```

They won't show anything unless the user is logged in... This way, you can simply include them wherever you need them and they display the data only as needed.

Comment: That is very true but doesn't really solve my problem. For example the editPageDochead.php include has a CSS link in it, which needs to sit inside the document head, but the adminBoot.php include has a session_start in it, which needs to site before any other HTML.

Comment: @Coop But your adminBoot.php file has already been called at the top of the page, so it won't muck up your session_start().

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where this is going. I currently have 3 includes on the page, but I only want 1. The problem is that the 3 includes are specifically placed at certain points in the HTML and the code they bring in need to be in those places...

Comment: @Coop You know that included files execute as if they were right there in the code. Therefore, you can place the entire top section into a php file and include the whole thing?

Comment: I can't really do that because I'm trying to integrate this CMS with existing sites. The doc heads may be different on each page and I want to keep them in tact, but just add in includes where needed.